# What is the difference between gulp-clean-css vs gulp-csso vs gulp-minify-css?

Tags: css, gulp, minify

Recently I learned gulp and I saw three gulp plugins called `gulp-clean-css`, `gulp-csso`, `gulp-minify-css` ( deprecated ).

I saw in internet but no question found like that, except this [website](https://www.npmtrends.com/gulp-clean-css-vs-gulp-csso-vs-gulp-minify) but it shows only graph of downloads.

So my question is

1. Which plugin I use in my big project to minify my multiple CSS
2. What is the cons and pros of above plugins

Comment: Also see benchmark https://goalsmashers.github.io/css-minification-benchmark/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CSSO](https://github.com/ben-eb/gulp-csso) (75 commits) is simply used to minify and generate source maps for pre-processed files.

[Clean-CSS](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css) (1583 commits) has a lot more options : it can remove units when they're not needed, convert colors for shorter declarations, **can remove duplicate rules**, restructure rules, etc.

I would suggest looking into [CSS Nano](https://github.com/cssnano/cssnano) (1923 commits) as well since it has the same options as Clean CSS but is used more widely since it is built on the PostCSS ecosystem. Here is the [list of all the possible optimisations](https://cssnano.co/optimisations/).

It basically depends of the complexity of your project and what you're currently using.

Comment: so cssnano is better than above plugins ?

Comment: which i  use in my system [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cssnano) or [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cssnano) ?

Comment: Since you're using gulp, you want to use is `gulp-cssnano`